# A question about the following theorem: $c(A\cup B)=c(A)\cup c(B)$.

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

Let there be a point $p\in(A\cup B)'$ such that some open sets containing it contain points in $A\setminus B$, and other open  sets containing it contain points in $B\setminus A$.

$A\setminus B=A-(A\cap B)$

Then $p$ is not a limit point of either $A$ or $B$. However, it is a limit point of $A\cup B$!! Is the theorem $c(A\cup B)=c(A)\cup c(B)$ untrue then?

EDIT: $c(A)$ is the closure of set $A$ in a topological space. $A'$ is the complement of set $A$ in the topological space

Comment: As of now, I think $c(A)\cup c(B)\subset c(A\cup B)$.

Comment: @ZevChonoles- thanks. I made the relevant clarifications

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such point: Let $p \in c(A \cup B)$, then any open set containing $p$ contains points of $A$ or $B$. Suppose there is an open set $U$ such that $p \in U$, $U \cap A = \emptyset$ and another open $V$ such that $p \in V$, $V \cap B\ne\emptyset$. Then $U \cap V$ is open $p \in U \cap V$, but $(U \cap V) \cap (A \cup B) = \emptyset$, contradicting $p \in c(A \cup B)$.

Hence, a point as you want, cannot exists, therefore $c(A \cup B) = c(A) \cup c(B)$.

Comment: We seem to have read the question differently...

Comment: @ZevChonoles Yes, indeed.

Comment: true. There will always be an open set containing said point and no point in $(A\cup B)$. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Let $X$ be our topological space. **Any point $p\in X$ whatsoever** has the property that

> some open sets containing it contain points in $A\setminus B$, and other open sets containing it contain points in $B\setminus A$

because $X$ is an open set, and contains every point of the topological space.

Comment: What I meant by that statement was there is an open set containing $p$ which contains a point in $A$, but not in $B$. $X$ is not such an open set.

Comment: @Ayush That's what you meant; it's not what you wrote. "A point in $A \setminus B$" is different from "Points in $A$, but not in $B$" -- I suggest you think about it.

Comment: @Lord_Farin- http://en.wikipedia.or/wiki/Complement_%28set_theory%29 says $B\setminus A=\{x\in B|x\notin A\}$. 
Am I missing something?

Comment: @Ayush: "*Contains points in $A\setminus B$*" does not in any way rule out **also** containing points in $B$, or anywhere else for that matter. It sounds like you meant "disjoint from $B$", i.e. "intersection with $B$ is empty".

Comment: For example, suppose $X=\mathbb{R}$, $A=[0,2]$, and $B=(1,3)$. Then we have $A\setminus B=[0,1]$, and $B\setminus A=(2,3)$. Note that $\mathbb{R}$ contains $\frac{1}{2}$ and $\frac{5}{2}$, and *therefore contains points in $A\setminus B$ and $B\setminus A$*.